# What does it mean for an OS to compile down to a function?

Tags: functional-programming, operating-systems, virtual-machine

I was reading the [Urbit docs](https://urbit.org/understanding-urbit/urbit-os/) and stopped at this paragraph (emphasis mine):

> The main thing to understand about our ‘overlay OS’, as we call it, is that the foundation is a single, simple function. This function is the Urbit OS virtual machine. We call it ‘Nock’. The entire Urbit OS system **compiles down** to Nock, and Nock is just 33 lines of code.

As per their other docs, [Nock seems to be this Turing-complete function](https://urbit.org/docs/tutorials/nock/definition/).

What I'm trying to get my head around is the "compiles down" wording. How can an operating system reduce to one single function?

Comment: A CPU is just a Turing-complete function that takes machine code as input and performs the side-effects described therein. You don't have any problems accepting the statement "The entire Windows OS compiles down to x86 machine code", do you?

Comment: "Nock" have chosen for their own reasons to use different terminology, or existing terminology to mean different things; it is prone to being obscure and somewhat mystical in its explanations.

Answer (score 1):

They mean that the operating system compiles to a *language* which is simple enough to be *executed* by a 33-line function.